# Як можна перекласти «makespan»

Tags: переклад, from-english

> В галузі дослідження операцій *makespan* проекта -- це відстань в часі від початку до завершення.

Поки на думку спадає лише *протяжність виконання*. Але *виконання* тут погано, бо вже сильно задіяно в інших подібних словосполученнях.

Тут найбільша складність полягає в тому як перекласти *make*. У *span* багато хороших перекладів, але не можу добрати, який тут підібрати для *make*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В книжці Катренко А. В. *Дослідження операцій*, Львів, "Магнолія-2006", 2009, 352 с. Розділ 5 *Планування на мережах* (с. 163 - 175) вживається термін **тривалість**. Тому зупинились на **тривалість плану**.

Answer (score 3):

Ну якщо брати приклад вживання цього слова із [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/makespan#Noun):

> If we don't reduce the makespan of that product, the order won't be
>   shipped on time.

То його можна перекласти як:

> Якщо ми не скоротимо **період/час виготовлення** цього продукту,
>   замовлення не буде доставлене вчасно.

Але як я розумію, контекст тут дещо інший ніж у вашому питанні. Ось на сторінці [Вікіпедії](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makespan) я знайшов статтю (звідки ви, напевно, і переклали визначення слова) і там є також приклад:

> If we let Shmuel feed all goats, then the makespan is 30.

Переклад:

> Якщо ми даму Шмулю погодувати всіх кіз, тоді **час виконання** (можливо ще
>   замінити на "**час виконання завдання**") буде 30 хвилин.

Якщо вам не подобається слово "виконання", то можна замінити його на "[завершення](http://sum.in.ua/s/zavershennja)", тобто вийде "**час завершення завдання**", або ж ще краще "**час для завершення завдання**" чи можна використати описовий переклад "**період/час за який буде виконане завдання**".

На жаль, це слово мені не вдалося знайти в жодному українсько-англійському онлайн словнику (серед них Глосб, Мета, Гугл, словник на сайті Академик).

А взагалі, було б добре якби ви надали саме те речення в якому вам потрібно перекласти це слово, щоб було легше підібрати влучний переклад.